# Upgrade project to ICEfaces 2.0

Tags: jsf, jboss5.x, icefaces

I have a project in JSF 1.2 and ICEfaces 1.8.

I have started the upgrade process to JSF 2.0 and ICEfaces 2.0 based on [this tutorial](http://wiki.icefaces.org/display/ICE/Converting+ICEfaces+1.8+Applications+to+ICEfaces+2)

I've DELETED old JSF and ICEfaces jars from my project and copied the new ones from icefaces 2 libs.

When I start JBoss I clearly see that JSF 2.0 jars are loaded but I do not understand why it still loads the ICEfaces 1.8 lib.

```
    15:37:07,431 INFO  [config] Initializing Mojarra (1.2_12-b01-FCS) for context '/
admin-console'
15:37:09,012 INFO  [D2DViewHandler]
ICEsoft Technologies, Inc.
ICEfaces 1.8.2
Build number: 7
Revision: 19321

15:37:09,089 WARN  [D2DViewHandler] JSF 2.0 libraries detected. This version of
ICEfaces is not supported on JSF 2.0. JSF 1.1 or 1.2 are required.
```

Do you see any reason?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I have not actually deleted all the old jars. Fixed now.